# How do I do an operation on a fixed time series for a large matrix of input variable combinations?

Tags: r

I am trying to perform a calculation on a time series using a combination of other variables as inputs. The calculation is dependent on four numeric variables. Each variable has the same number of possible values I want in this permutation (the variable name is Ia).

```
Ia1 <- seq(1,10,1)
Ia2 <- seq(1,10,1)
Ia3 <- seq(1,10,1)
Ia4 <- seq(1,10,1)
```

Making a data frame that has all four possible combinations of numbers in Ia1:Ia4 is key to calculating what I need to calculate:

```
Iacombos <- expand.grid(Ia1=Ia1, Ia2=Ia2, Ia3=Ia3, Ia4=Ia4)
```

heads(Iacombos) results in:

```
Ia1 Ia2 Ia3 Ia4
1   1   1   1
2   1   1   1
3   1   1   1
4   1   1   1
5   1   1   1
6   1   1   1
```

Now for the time series I want to use in the calculation. Let's use some sample data:

```
tseries <- data.frame("time"=seq(c(ISOdate(2000,3,20)), by = "day", length.out = 20),
           "p"=rnorm(20, 0.9, 0.35))

head(tseries)
            time         p
2000-03-20 07:00:00 0.7445015
2000-03-21 07:00:00 0.8044078
2000-03-22 07:00:00 0.5509089
2000-03-23 07:00:00 0.2055671
2000-03-24 07:00:00 0.9122942
2000-03-25 07:00:00 0.7749430
```

Now to get to the part that you can actually understand: I want to create a loop or apply a function for each row of Iacombos, where each value in the entire p column of the time series is multiplied by Ia[i,1] and then summed and stored, then each value of p is multiplied by Ia[i,2] and then summed and stored, same for Ia[i,3] and Ia[i,4]. For each "cumsum" or sum of Ia[i,j], that value is thrown into the Iacombos data frame in columns Q1 through Q4. Looking something like this:

```
Ia1 Ia2 Ia3 Ia4 Q1                        Q2               
1   1   1   1   sum(Ia1[1]*each P value)  sum(Ia2[1]*each P value)
2   1   1   1   sum(Ia1[2]*each P value)  sum(Ia2[2]*each P value)
3   1   1   1   
4   1   1   1 
5   1   1   1
6   1   1   1
```

With the data filled down, and including Q3 and Q4, although I couldn't fit them in the space.

Answer (score 0):

Since `(ab + ac) = a(b + c)`, there's a very simple solution:

```
Qvalues = Iacombos * sum(tseries$p)
names(Qvalues) = paste0("Q", 1:4)
Output = cbind(Iacombos, Qvalues)

   Ia1 Ia2 Ia3 Ia4        Q1       Q2       Q3       Q4
1:   1   1   1   1  20.09752 20.09752 20.09752 20.09752
2:   2   1   1   1  40.19504 20.09752 20.09752 20.09752
3:   3   1   1   1  60.29256 20.09752 20.09752 20.09752
4:   4   1   1   1  80.39007 20.09752 20.09752 20.09752
5:   5   1   1   1 100.48759 20.09752 20.09752 20.09752
6:   6   1   1   1 120.58511 20.09752 20.09752 20.09752
```

if you have a more complex operation to do row-wise, use `apply`.

```
apply(Iacombos, 1, function(x) ...)
```

'x' is now a vector of `Ia1-4` in each row (so vector of length 4).

```
apply(Iacombos, 1, function(x) sapply(x, function(y) sum(y * tseries$p)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I feel bad now, since, for simplicity's sake, I stated I wanted the product of Ia and the P values, when my actual problem involves a complex equation. I was using multiplicative product as a surrogate so it wouldn't bog people down in the answers. Is there a more generic way to do what you described that is independent on the distributive property of multiplication? Thanks for the response!

Comment: Can you explain exactly what your last line is doing specifically?

Comment: @AndMan21 It's saying "Take each row of Iacombos, and apply this function `function(x)` to it."

Comment: @AndMan21 Then the `function(x)` body sapply is saying "With this row you got passed down, take each of the four elements and return the sum of that element * tseries$p".